# Unexpected error in Array append with Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode6

```
    var playerOneArray : Array<(Int,Int,Int)> = []
    var currentPerson = 1
    var currentWeapon = 1
    var currentRoom = 1
    var currentPlayer = 1

    currentPerson = everyPicker.selectedRowInComponent(0)
    currentWeapon = everyPicker.selectedRowInComponent(1)
    currentRoom = everyPicker.selectedRowInComponent(2)
    currentPlayer = playerPicker.selectedRowInComponent(0)

    //In an if statement
    playerOneArray.append(currentRoom, currentPerson, currentWeapon) as (Int,Int,Int)
    // Error tuple types () and (Int,Int,Int) have a different number of elements (0 vs. 3)
```

even if i take away the as int,int,int there is still an error and i don't know why this is happening. the error that comes up if i take it away is accessing members of protocol 'int' is unimplemented.

Comment: Looks like you're missing parens `.append((a,b,c) as (Int,Int,Int))`

Answer (score 2):

You are not closing the parenthesis of the `append` call.

However, because swift knows playerOneArray is an array of 3 Ints. You can simply pass the append method the 3 variables as follows:

```
 playerOneArray.append(currentRoom, currentPerson, currentWeapon)
```

Assuming (currentRoom, currentPerson, currentWeapon) is a tuple of Int values. This will store (currentRoom, currentPerson, currentWeapon) into playerOneArray[0].

As a side note, it seems you are wanting an array of players which holds each players details. If this is the case you should rename the `playerOneArray` to `players` and simply add each player's information. That way each index will represent the players information (the tuple of Ints).

Comment: swiftc returns an error `Missing argument for parameter #2 in call.` on this.  It attempts to expand the tuple into three parameters.

Comment: @Brian, yes that is correct, the append method is smart enough to recognize the parameters of the tuple so you can simply pass the 3 Ints. I have updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea but your syntax is incorrect.

The way it's written, Swift is looking for a method with the signature:

```
func append(Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int)
```

That is, a function named `append` that takes three Ints and returns a tuple of three Ints.  The error you're getting is probably because Swift sees the definition `append(T) -> ()` and is complaining that you return 3 components rather than zero.

You could try to just pass a tuple by adding parenthesis but this would fail because Swift treats a single tuple as a list of parameters so it looks for a signature `append(Int, Int, Int) -> ()` which does not exist:

```
playerOneArray.append((currentRoom, currentPerson, currentWeapon)) // Missing argument for parameter #2 in call.
```

The correct solution looks very close to what you were doing (maybe you were hinted in that direction):

```
playerOneArray.append((currentRoom, currentPerson, currentWeapon) as (Int,Int,Int))
```

This tells Swift that you mean that tuple to really be a tuple and it successfully finds the signature: `append((Int, Int, Int)) -> ()`.

As a side note, tuples are intended for transferring data more so than storing it.  If you expect this data to persist long term you should put it in a struct:

```
struct Player {
    var person:Int
    var weapon:Int
    var room:Int
}

var playerOneArray:[Player] = []

let player = Player(
    person: everyPicker.selectedRowInComponent(0),
    weapon: everyPicker.selectedRowInComponent(1),
    room: everyPicker.selectedRowInComponent(2))

playerOneArray.append(player)
```

Answer (score 0):

`append` is getting three parameters instead of one tuple. Try this:

`playerOneArray.append((currentRoom, currentPerson, currentWeapon))`